Why $H_3(S^3)\to H_2(T)$ is injective ? (Homology of knot complement )
I have a question about the homology of the complementary space of knots.

I was able to find $H_2(X)$ and $H_1(X)$ ( $X\colon $ knot complement ) by using MV sequences, but I was not able to derive $H_3(X)$ successfully using MV sequences, and I was doing research.

In these two documents,

https://www.komazawa-u.ac.jp/~w3c/lecture/pdf/poincare.pdf page7

https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/27862/1/bMATH_2022_vanderWeideRM.pdf page15

It is stated in a natural way that $H_3(S^3)\stackrel{\partial}{\to}H_2(T)$ is injective, without any particular reflections, why is this? As far as I know, it must be a finite set for $\partial\colon$ surjective $\Rightarrow \partial \colon$ injective to be valid.

(In a manner of speaking, I understand how to use Alexander's dual theorem and how to use coated homology.)

$X$ is (homotopy equvalent to) a compact 3-dim manifold with boundary, the fact that $H_3(X)=0$ can be seen by choosing any triangulation of $X$ (in a 3-cycle all the simplicies would need to have the same coefficient and the simplicies adjacent to the boundary of $X$ would need coefficient 0). But you probably want a different method.

@user8268 That is correct. I already understand how to do that and want a way to derive it from the MV sequence.
